# Lucene search for keywords embedded in text

Tags: lucene

Below is my problem statement. Please let me know how I can achieve this through Lucene 4.3.1. I did look at the different default queries, but nothing seemed to meet my requirement.
If this is not possible in Lucene, is there any other software that can help me achieve this. Also please note that, I have a very stringent turn around time for this, so the search needs to be done pretty quick. I am looking at about 10 milliseconds at the max

I have a file with list of names (in format - "first name" "middle name" "last name"), may be around 10K.  These names have to be indexed, so that I can perform search for the incoming query.

For e.g.

List of names that will be indexed

- First M Last
- First MI Last
- First N Las
- and some other names

Case 1:
Below query should return First M Last from the index

- Hello, how are you doing First M Last today
- Hello, how are you doing Last First M today
- Hello, how are you doing Lst M First today

Case 2:
Below query should not return anything. Note that the names have some other text in between them.

- Hello, how are you doingFirst some text M some text Last today

Case 3:
I should be able to do fuzzy search too. Below query should return First M Last from the index.

- Hello, how are you doing Ferst M Last today
- Hello, how are you doing Last Ferst M today
- Hello, how are you doing Last M Ferst today

I did try with proximity query, but since the input is very random, I am not able to use it.

Comment: I'm having trouble following what the question is. Can you stress both what you tried and what's not working with what you tried?

Comment: This seems like a very backward use case. A couple of thoughts toward an implementation, to make sure only adjacent elements of the query are used, you'll need to either pick out the relevant piece of the query, or perhaps separate it into [Shingles](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleAnalyzerWrapper.html) (though I would avoid using Shingles like this if you have an alternative). If you are asking if Lucene already has some class that will handle parsing a query with the sort of logic you are looking for, I would think decidedly not.

Comment: It is not possible for me to pick the relevant piece of query, since the input can be anything. I did look at Shingles, but they dont seem to change the order. And Yes, it looks like it is not supported out of the box. The only thing I could think of is put all the permutations of the names in index and search for an exact match. This doesnt seem to be an efficient way. Also it will not work if there is a name which has ten parts. Permutation will be too costly in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd have better luck running an indexing service like http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/tutorial.html and writing scripts to both populate it with your data and query it as you needed.

Please note that what you say are queries look like results to me, so it's not clear what your expectations are. Normally you'd only get the data out that you put in.

Comment: My expectation is, queries that I have posted above are the input that user types in. For the user entered input I need to pull up the name that is present in my index. Also please note that, I am looking for Lucene, so that I can embed in my application instead of a separate service like solr